# SCSS specificity problem with Fontawesome Icons

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I want to color a fontawesome icon in a laravel/vue3 project but it seems to be impossible to overwrite an `asterisk selector` inside of a SCSS file from withing a vue component.

File structure:

[image]

I want to define a global color property in `app.scss` and overwrite it in v-nav.vue to color a fontawesome icon.

**app.scss**:

```
* {
  color: red;
}
```

**v-nav.vue**:

```
<template>
    <fa class="icon-lang" :icon="[ 'fas', 'language' ]"></fa>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.icon-lang {
  color: blue;
  path {
    color: blue;
  }
}
svg {
  color: blue;
  path {
    color: blue;
  }
}
</style>
```

Every class selector should have a higher specificity than the `*` selector and I can change the color of all font strings in the project. Why can't I change the `color` property of the icons?

Comment: `https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/u/universal/` is saying that `as the universal selector holds no specificity value at all`. All other classes have higher specificity than the `asterisk` except `svg/.svg-class` selectors so I assume that this is no normal behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while; you're right that the specificity is 0, but what I was thinking of was the danger that `*` is *universal*; it applies to *everything* (even `html` and `body`), so most cases where it is overriding something is because there's another property where a value is set that your targeted element is inheriting from, and it becomes quite difficult to find the source of inheritance the more elements or more complexity you hav.e

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks